# Providing links to page sections via textblocks or similar in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-3.5, textblock

I have a data entry form in WPF built using a Scrollviewer with various elements inside of it, primarily richtextboxes. These allow a user to enter whatever data is needed, adding new sections as required. Down the right hand side border, I have a dynamic list of all the sections currently present, providing a visual representation of the overall form.

What I ideally want to be able to do, is allow the user to click on a section on the right hand panel (currently each section is labeled in the list using a textblock), and be taken to that section in the scrollviewer on the main page, similar to hyper links in a webpage to jump to page content sections.

Does anyone know if this is possible in WPF?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you need `FrameworkElement.BringIntoView` method. It's described [here on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.bringintoview.aspx)

Comment: That worked pretty much perfectly, cheers! Just got to try and tweak where it pulls it into view now so its at the top of the page, shouldn't be hard though ^_^